# Геолокация в Android приложениях

Tags: геолокация, android

Здравствуйте.

Мне нужно, чтобы моё приложения выполняло некую функцию при смене геолокации смартфона. Например, мы задали конкретную точку на карте, указали радиус, и нужно, чтобы при попадании смартфона в данную площадь пользователю выводилось информационное сообщение в строке уведомлений. При этом функция должна работать при спячем режиме.

Я так понял, нужно с чем-то использовать Broatcast receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью Geofence из Google Play Services реализовать достаточно просто.

[Пост на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/210162/)

[Описание на developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать геозоны и смотреть действия пользователя. Например, чтобы добавить геозону:

```
mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
// Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
// geofence.
.setRequestId(entry.getKey())

.setCircularRegion(
        entry.getValue().latitude,
        entry.getValue().longitude,
        Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
)
.setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
.setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
.build());
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, можно пожалуйста давать по разкутее ответы?